# Parse a model field to string inside a template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

So I've got this template that get's a bunch of products from a collection of Product Models, and I want to pass the name of the object, or the object itself to a view in views.py.

But it seems that I always get an error message when I try to send the product model itself with a link like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'show_cart' product=product %}">Add to cart</a>
```

I get an error like this:

```
Reverse for 'show_cart' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
'{'product': <Product: Gul Juice>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
['handlekurv/(?P<product>[-\\w]+)/$']
```

So I tried to format it into a string with this:

```
<a href="{% url 'show_cart' product=product.name|stringformat:"s" %}">Add to Cart</a>
```

But then I get this error instead:

```
Reverse for 'show_cart' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
'{'product': 'Gul Juice'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
['handlekurv/(?P<product>[-\\w]+)/$']
```

Here is the url:

```
url(r'^handlekurv/(?P<product>[-\w]+)/$', views.show_cart, name='show_cart'),
```

And the first part of the view:

```
def show_cart(request, product):        
    if 'cart' in request.session:
        request.session['cart'].append(product.id)
    else:
        request.session['cart'] = [product]
    return render(request, 'shopping/show_cart.html', {
        'cart': request.session['cart'],
    })
```

Comment: show your whole `show_cart` view

Comment: added the rest, trough it probably don't work yet anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot pass an object in a link. You could change the `__unicode__`/`__str__` function to return some string you want, but changing the magic methods just for building some url in one template is overkill. You can work with product's id, e.g:

```
def show_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    # ...
```

and in template:

```
<a href="{% url 'show_cart' product.id %}">Add to cart</a>
```

urlconf:

```
url(r'^handlekurv/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', views.show_cart, name='show_cart'),
```

which is the standard way of doing things like this

Comment: Yeah I thought that I couldn't just send the object itself. Thus I tried to find a way to make it a string. But the id worked.

The product.id just sends an int to the view if I understand correctly?

Comment: @AndreasHalvorsenTollånes since you are saving only the object id into session anyway, I think there is no need for objects

Comment: @AndreasHalvorsenTollånes yep, `product_id` is an int

Comment: Yeah my first plan was to just save a list of strings that I could call back and fill out from the collection later on in the shopping cart. But a list of ID's work as well.

Comment: @AndreasHalvorsenTollånes yo id is better, less memory malloc